# Which file is Perl's diamond operator (null file handle) currently reading from?

Tags: perl, diamond-operator

I'm using Perl's *diamond* `<>` operator to read from files specified on the command line.

I'd like to be able to report messages like `"Trouble on line $. of file $FILENAME"`, but how can I tell which file is currently used by the diamond?

Comment: Just a note: Using $ARGV is dangerous for detecting which file is open, e.g.: mycmd file.1 file.1 file.1 (multiple files with the same name). Stick with using `eof`.

Comment: The perceived problem with “external packages” is frustrating and absurd. Most Perl modules are just source files with a `.pm` extension, and no installation process is necessary. By default `@INC` includes the current directory as `.`, so just copying the requisite files to the same directory as the source will make the package available and fulfill the dependency.

Comment: @Borodin if something is available straight in the language, I prefer to know about it. As simple as that.

Comment: It would be perverse to recommend a solution that required you to download and install a Perl module if the same effect could be achieved without. Your stated preference looks very much like the common incantation that a solution *must not* involve installing a module, which belies the fact that anything copied from a Stack Overflow solution is also *"external"*. You should also remember that there are many *core* modules that are installed with Perl by default, and it would be harsh to require a solution that excluded those.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

```
    $ARGV

Contains the name of the current file when reading from <> .
```

But also consider `$.` in perlvar. If you do this with `perl -n` it might not turn out the way you want it, because **the counter is not reset** in the `perl -n` use case.

> ```
> $.
> ```
>
> Current line number for the last filehandle accessed.
>
> Each filehandle in Perl counts the number of lines that have been read
>   from it. (Depending on the value of `$/` , Perl's idea of what
>   constitutes a line may not match yours.) When a line is read from a
>   filehandle (via `readline()` or `<>` ), or when `tell()` or `seek()` is called
>   on it, `$.` becomes an alias to the line counter for that filehandle.
>
> You can adjust the counter by assigning to `$.` , but this will not
>   actually move the seek pointer. Localizing `$.` will not localize the
>   filehandle's line count. Instead, it will localize perl's notion of
>   which filehandle `$.` is currently aliased to.
>
> `$.` is reset when the filehandle is closed, but not when an open
>   filehandle is reopened without an intervening `close()`. For more
>   details, see I/O Operators in perlop. Because `<>` never does an
>   explicit close, line numbers increase across ARGV files (but see
>   examples in eof).
>
> You can also use `HANDLE->input_line_number(EXPR)` to access the line
>   counter for a given filehandle without having to worry about which
>   handle you last accessed.
>
> Mnemonic: many programs use "." to mean the current line number.

Here's an example:

```
$ perl -nE 'say "$., $ARGV";' foo.pl bar.pl
1, foo.pl
2, foo.pl
3, foo.pl
4, foo.pl
5, foo.pl
6, foo.pl
7, foo.pl
8, foo.pl
9, foo.pl
10, foo.pl
11, foo.pl
12, foo.pl
13, bar.pl
14, bar.pl
15, bar.pl
```

If you want it to reset, you need to check for `eof` at the end of your read loop (*thanks @Borodin*). Also see the [perldoc for `eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html):

```
$ perl -nE 'say "$., $ARGV"; close ARGV if eof' foo.pl bar.pl
```

Comment: yep. I knew about $. already. Thanks for $ARGV: for some reason, it evaded my eyes.

Comment: @sylvainulg look at the example, it just confused me a lot. It's not reset if the handle is just reopened to another file.

Comment: ok, so I could want to do `$.=1 if $ARGV ne $lastfilename` to avoid confusing users ...

Comment: Yes, it seems so. `$ perl -nE 'if ($lastfilename ne $ARGV) { $lastfilename = $ARGV; $.= 1; } say "$., $ARGV";' foo.pl bar.pl` - Restarts at 1 for bar.pl =)

Comment: The canonical method is to write `close ARGV if eof` at the end of your read loop. That will reset `$.` to zero.

Comment: @simbabque: It's documented well in [perldoc -f eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html)

Comment: First, I was confused about this *`But also consider $. in perlvar.`* part. But the OP indeed included this into the question. I've another use case (checking file names against content patterns) and here the first part of your answer is exactly what I was searching for.