# Perl - while (<>) file handling

Tags: perl, while-loop, cycle, filehandle

A simple program with `while( <> )` handles files given as arguments (`./program 1.file 2.file 3.file`) and standard input of Unix systems.

I think it concatenates them together in one file and work is line by line. The problem is, how do I know that I'm working with the first file? And then with the second one.

For a simple example, I want to print the file's content in one line.

```
while( <> ){
    print "\n" if (it's the second file already);
    print $_;
}
```

Comment: looks pretty much similar to the following SO topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584944/which-file-is-perl-diamond-operator-currently-reading-from

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The diamond operator does not concatenate the files, it just opens and reads them consecutively. How you control this depends on how you need it controlled. A simple way to check when we have read the last line of a file is to use `eof`:

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;             # remove newline
    print;             # print the line
    print "\n" if eof; # at end of file, print a newline
}
```

You can also consider a counter to keep track of which file in order you are processing

```
$counter++ if eof;
```

Note that this count will increase by one at the *last line* of the file, so do not use it prematurely.

If you want to keep track of line number `$.` in the current file handle, you can `close` the ARGV file handle to reset this counter:

```
while (<>) {
    print "line $. : ", $_;
    close ARGV if eof;
}
```

Comment: See `perldoc -f eof` for more information on detecting the boundaries between the files read by the `<>` operator.

Answer (score 13):

The `<>` is a special case of the readline operator. It usually takes a filehandle: `<$fh>`.

If the filehandle is left out, then the the magic `ARGV` filehandle is used.

If no command line arguments are given, then `ARGV` is `STDIN`. If command line arguments are given, then `ARGV` will be `open`ed to each of those in turn. This is similar to

```
# Pseudocode
while ($ARGV = shift @ARGV) {
  open ARGV, $ARGV or do{
    warn "Can't open $ARGV: $!";
    next;
  };
  while (<ARGV>) {
    ...; # your code
  }
}
```

The `$ARGV` variable is real, and holds the filename of the file currently opened.

Please be aware that the two-arg form of `open` (which is probably used here behind the scenes), is quite unsafe. The filename `rm -rf * |` may not do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the current file for `<>` is contained in special `$ARGV` [variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

You can cross-match your list of files from `@ARGV` parameter array with current file name to get the file's position in the list. Assuming the only parameters you expect are filenames, you can simply do:

```
my %filename_positions = map { ( $ARGV[$_] => $_ ) } 0..$#ARGV;

while (<>) {
    my $file_number = $filename_positions{$ARGV};
    #... if ($file_number == 0) { #first file     
}
```